# Are there rules on what are the correct vowels

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, grammar-dikduk

I understand that, excluding the 24 books of Tenach, in all the Torah books (i.e. Mishna, Talmud...) we have no tradition on specific vowels.

(I was reading a Shulchan Aruch Harav vowelized, in which they wrote about the word "sesuma" that the nikud (vowelization) is "sesuma" but people call it "setuma".)

Are there rules about what the nikud needs to be (the right way of reading it) in these Torah books?

If yes, what book do you recommend that summarizes these rules?

Comment: First of all, the people putting nikudos in many of these seforim are not always great at it. Second of all you might not gain much. Will you start saying reish galvassa instead of galusa just cause it's correct? If you are in a major yeshiva and say coy they'll dry oh you mean kvi? How about chasicha instead of chaticha. And of course we can give rabi oshaaya back his name from being called oshiya.

Comment: @user6591 i heard same by r' yosai and not r' yosi.-- but i want to know are their rules that are written or it just comes naturally

Comment: @hazoriz i know. I'm not trying to discourage you. Just pointing out that society has its colloquial pronunciations And won't accept the proper way:) In most mishnayos there is a pirush that points out proper pronunciations. I think it's the mishna rishona/achrona. Also in the gemara the Yaavetz does it occasionally. But i think it's hard to have a rule book considering how many languages the mishna and gemara is made up from.

Comment: @Hazoriz my personal goal is to convince everyone that the name Rava is really raba. Read Targum which has nikudos. There its never a word spelled like that where the middle letter is a v sound. Its always b. And now we understand how his name and Rabbah got mixed up so many times in shaas. The pronunciation Is almost the same!

Comment: I thought it was sethuma?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Hebrew#Grammar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_grammar

Comment: The "sesuma/setuma" example made more sense before you edited it, when you had an "oi".  Now it just looks like a suf/tuf consonant debate with the same vowelization.

Comment: @Mike my question includes the nikud of dogesh (tof and sof). When is it tof and when sof?

Comment: Yes, there are rules.

Comment: @Daniel thank you, what are they?

Comment: I can't just list all of the rules just like I can't just list all of the English grammar rules. There are a lot of them, but as a start, you might want to read up on BeGeD-KeFeT letters and t'nuot gedolot and ketanot

Comment: @hazoriz My understanding is that in Tanach the nikkud has been passed down from the time of the Masoretes.  Of course, this only means that we know how the Masoretes of the early common era pronounced the words. The Jews of Babylon and Jerusalem probably each had their own pronunciation for (and therefore rules for pronouncing) certain words which appear in the Talmud.